# Upload image from frontend and display it on user’s profile page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

On my website I let registered members create multiple profiles, each of these with their own avatar picture.

On the Create Profile page, I have this input to submit the avatar...
[image]

... and get it displayed on the Profile page:
[image]

How can I recreate the same, uploading one more picture from Create Profile and display it on Profile page?

I know where the source files for each page are located, but unfortunately I’m unable to recreate it..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need a **3 step** process to upload the image file, store it and send it to the front-end users.

- If your app is an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and you don't want to reload the page in the user's browser, you'll need a JS process to read the file from a [file button](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_fileupload.asp) and send it to your server (through [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) as a [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) for example)
- Then your server should be able to handle the formdata object request and read file content from it. Once done, you have to save it in a secure server-side location.
- Finally (again in case of an SPA) your server should be able to answer the picture data when the client asks it

  - The server should be able to give the avatar's URL when asked by the client (with a [Restful API](https://www.restapitutorial.com/) for example)
  - The server should be able to give access to the image when the client uses the image's url